# List files inside GCS's bucket in servlet and serve it with blob

Tags: android, google-app-engine, servlets, google-cloud-storage, google-api-java-client

I have been on to this topic since 4 days. I want to download the files listed in Google Cloud Storage into my App. For this :

1) I have created my application in GAE and set my Google Cloud Storage project and created my bucket.

2) Now I want to write a servlet which List the files inside "mybucket" and serve it with blob which I will read  inside my android app (via Http response )and save to the SD card or memory. To do this I have collected piece of code , but I have no clue how to put it together.

I am not even sure if I am doing it right. ANy help or link or suggestions are highly appreciated. Please let me know if you need any further information.

Code which will go in servlet to implement the step 2):

```
Storage.Objects.List listObjects = storage.objects().list("mybucket");
Objects objects;
do {
  objects = listObjects.execute();
  for (StorageObject object : objects.getItems()) {
    // Do things!
  }
  listObjects.setPageToken(objects.getNextPageToken());
} while (null != objects.getNextPageToken());

BlobstoreService blobstoreService = BlobstoreServiceFactory.getBlobstoreService();
BlobKey blobKey = blobstoreService.createGsBlobKey(
    "/gs/"+"androidbucket"+"/"+filename");
blobstoreService.serve(blobKey, resp);
```

Now my question regarding this code snippet is how "Storage.Objects.List" is going to know under which project it has look for "mybucket"?? Because I read this line under my application settings on GAE "When creating new buckets, or listing the buckets owned by a project, you must specify the x-goog-project-id HTTP header in order to identify which project you are using."

EDIT: Also I am not able to compile my servlet on "Storage.Objects.List". I have downloaded Cloud Storage API from this link :https://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/wiki/APIs#Cloud_Storage_API .. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your quote:

> When creating new buckets, or listing the buckets owned by a project,
>   you must specify the x-goog-project-id HTTP header in order to
>   identify which project you are using.

This refers to listing **buckets**. You are listing **objects** in a bucket.

If you were retrieving a list of buckets, you'd have to pass in a project ID. The [reference for buckets.list](https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/buckets/list) shows how to do this:

```
Storage.Buckets.List listBuckets = storage.buckets().list("myproject");
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @jterrace..that clears my confusion..Also I am not able to compile "Storage.Object.List" in my servlet..I have downloaded Cloud Storage API but not sure which jar file I need to add in my servlet project. Link to Cloud Storage API :https://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/wiki/APIs#Cloud_Storage_API